# Position SVG path under image with dynamic height

Tags: reactjs, svg, position

I'm trying to position a custom path underneath images that are being loaded, the images will have the same width but the height will vary.
I'm using react-measure to get width, height of my image in svg to later on use that height to position the next element, but due to presumably aspect ratio, I get wrong values.

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1000 2000">
  <svg
    x="150"
    y="200"
  >
    <Measure
      bounds
      onResize={ (contentRef) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ imgDimensions: contentRef.bounds }));
      } }
    >
      { ({ measureRef }) => (
        <svg x="0">
          <image className={ classes.img } ref={ measureRef } width="200" xlinkHref={ image } />
        </svg>
      ) }
    </Measure>
    <rect x="5" y={ this.state.imgDimensions.height } height="2" width={ width } />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

Example values:

```
imgDimensions:
bottom: 504.6000061035156
height: 176.39999389648438
left: 595
right: 835
top: 328.20001220703125
width: 240
```

and how it's positioned:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOh6v.jpg

That black line should be exactly where the image ends.

But if I resize the website and refresh it - this is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueULS.jpg

Comment: If your goal is simply to have a black line on the bottom of the image, why not just use CSS and add a bottom-border to the image...

Comment: @Ted because this is a simple example I've given, what I actually have in code are complex shapes and it is required for it to be in svg

Comment: I'd have to see the rest of your code, I'm not sure what `<Measure/>` does, but it probably wouldn't do much good till after the image is loaded.

Comment: @Ted well, this is in react, so once the image is measured it rerenders everything with new values passed through the state

Comment: Yes, I am very well versed in React, I just don't see a measure/set state call in an onLoad() handler for the image. On initial render, the image isn't loaded yet, so there wouldn't be anything to measure. Same with setting a new image url--you'd need to set state after it loads.

Comment: @ted `onResize={ (contentRef) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({ imgDimensions: contentRef.bounds }));
      } }` and I also posted a json in the question, you can clearly see I'm getting the values of that image